# Not able to parse the geometry LineString from GEOSwift library to show polyline in MapView

Tags: swift, parsing, mkmapview, geojson, geoswift

I have `geojson` file to show in Mapview. It contains thousands of coordaantes under the type "`LineString`". So, for parsing I used "`GEOSwift`" library.

But, while parsing time its not able to getting the data from `LineString` and its getting out of the condition from following.

```
                    if let item = item as? LineString {
```

The code is

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let geoJSONURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "LineString", withExtension: "geojson") {
                do {
                    var overlays = [MKPolyline]()
                    let features = try Features.fromGeoJSON(geoJSONURL)
                    for item in features! {
                        if let item = item as? LineString {
                            let polyLine = item.mapShape() as! MKPolyline
                            overlays.append(polyLine)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // add overlays to map
                        self.mapView.addOverlays(overlays)
                    }

                } catch {

                }
            }
        }
```

Even tried like following, but, showing compile time errors.

```
let geometryDict = item["geometry"]
let lineStringType = geometryDict["type"]
```

The sample data of `geojson` is like

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection”,”features":[{"type":"Feature","id":1,"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-61.4127132774969,42.9804121510986],[-61.412698736004,62.9807528172026],[-61.4126676674304,42.9808383428383]]},{"type":"Feature","id":2,"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-61.4124601404427,32.9810257092771],[-61.4124646891238,32.9810320381762],[-61.412690615116,32.9813462742651]]}
```

The hierarchy is like PFA.

Can anyone suggest me, where I am doing wrong?

[image]

I have followed following link completely, but, they did not given example for LineString.

https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift

Comment: Please describe logic behind `Features.fromGeoJSON()` method.

Comment: It is doing Jsonserialization, please check GEOSwift.swift file https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the variables inspector I see that you are accessing the element wrong way. Use the next expression to access the first `LineString` in `features` sequence:

`if let item = item.geometries[0] as? LineString {`

Comment: You saved my day. Working perfectly. Thanks so much. You are a genius.